# Having trouble launching app on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, reactjs, digital-ocean, create-react-app

So I'm fairly new to the web dev world, and this will be the first site of mine to go live. I'm using create-react-app with a nodejs backend.  I've been trying to figure this out for days and my client is getting impatient with me. I've been following this tutorial:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/i-built-this-now-what-how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-a-digitalocean-droplet-662de0fe3f48

I'm at the point where I type in "ssh@" and it asks for your ssh passphrase. It doesn't recognize my passphrase. Every attempt just causes it to ask again like this:

Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa':

Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa':

Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa':

I reset my passphrase, had it email me my new one, and got the same result. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: no way you can recover the passphrase. What you should do is declare the keys as lost to the issuer so that they revoke your certificate. Then, you have to create a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a Droplet on Digital Ocean, you should get an email with your root password for the `root` user, and also the IP address.

Let's say that these credentials are as follows:

- password: 123456
- IP address: 123.456.78.90

To connect to this server, you would have to use ssh. Using Bash on Linux (or Terminal on mac, or Ash on Alpine, etc.) the syntax would be as follows to connect as the `root` user.

`ssh root@123.456.78.90`

at which point, you will be asked if you trust the certificate and you can answer `yes`. you will then be asked if you want to remember the certificate and you can also answer `yes`.

Finally, you will be asked for your password and you can type `123456`

Also, you may have checked to use passwordless authentication.

If this is the case, you need to ensure Digital Ocean and SSH have access to this secret https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/